# Как правильно вывести данные?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть функция `get_some_body`. В ней есть разные значения, но нужно мне одно, выходит такой код:

```
for who in command.get_some_body(gde=gde):
   who_list = [who['threadId']]
   print(who_list)
```

Выводит это нужные значения, но мне нужно чтобы эти значения были значениями в листе, к примеру

`who_list=['Odin','Dva']`

Вместо один, два и тд должны идти значения, которые получил из функции. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте генераторы списков:

```
whoList = [who['threadId'] for who in command.get_some_body(gde=gde)]
```